# Unity Lerp in Seconds - List of Points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have list of translations and rotations for a gameobject with timeframe.

Example (translation):

```
Point 1: (X1, Y1, Z1) Current Time T1 
Point 2: (X2, Y2, Z2) Current Time T2 
Point 3: (X3, Y3, Z3) Current Time T3
```

...

In this case, I need a coroutine with Lerp from Point 1 to 2 with (T2-T1) seconds. After, from Point 2 to 3 with T3-T2 seconds... The point is, each movement should wait the completion of previous one. The delta time between points is roughly 0.1 seconds.

How should I do it? In addition, I also have the rotations (Rx1-n,Ry1-n,Rz1-n) similar to translations.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried already? Can you explain how you have those points stored? Are coroutines a requirement?

Also, have you tried to look for an answer on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)? What about posting this question there instead?

Comment: I did not try GameDev, I did not know it. For the points, I have a gameobject which is animated via physics calculation. My purpose is, due to network lag problems, instead of calculating physics on masterclient and sync them on clients, I calculate the physics and export the position/rotations of each gameobject. Then I will just neglect the physics and just animate them in all masterclient and other clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement can be done in a simple Coroutine like

```
// Moves a given object from A to B within given duration
IEnumerator MoveWithinSeconds(Transform obj, Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float duration)
{
    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        // will always be a factor between 0 and 1
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // optional ease-in and ease-out
        // factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0,1,factor);

        // linear interpolate the position
        obj.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, factor);

        // increase timePassed by time since last frame
        // using Min to avoid overshooting
        timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, duration - timePassed);

        // "pause" the routine here, render the frame
        // and continue from here in the next one
        yield return null;
    }

    // just to be sure apply the target position in the end
    obj.position = target;
}
```

and then simply iterate your elements from another Coroutine like

```
// the object you want to move
public Transform obj;
// your waypoints class with position and time stamp
public List<WAYPOINT>() waypoints;

IEnumerator MovementRoutine()
{
    // if 0 or only 1 waypoint then it makes no sense to go on
    if(waypoints.Count <= 1) yield break;

    // pick the first item
    var fromPoint = waypoints[0];
    // since you already have the first start the iteration with the second item
    for(var i = 1; i < waypoints.Count; i++)
    {
        var toPoint = waypoints[i];
        var fromPosition = fromPoint.position;
        var toPosition = toPoint.position;
        var duration = toPoint.time - fromPoint.time;

        // this executes and at the same time waits(yields) until the MoveWithinSeconds routine finished
        yield return MoveWithinSeconds(obj, fromPosition, toPosition, duration);

        // update fromPoint for the next step
        fromPoint = toPoint;
    }
}
```

Same can be done for rotations. Note however that rotating in eulerspace by only XYZ is a bit tricky in some conditions. You should probably rather store and use Quaternion with XYZW.

---

Note: This will work well as long as your frame-rate is high enough / the delta time big enough. The problem is that `yield return` postpones the following code at least 1 frame. So in cases where the delta time becomes smaller then the frame-rate it will not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much derHugo! I will try it today and if I could succeed :)

Comment: `public class WAYPOINT
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public float time;

        public WAYPOINT(Vector3 P, float t)
        {
            position = P;
            time = t;
        }
    }

    public void AddWaypoints()
    {
        waypoints.Add(new WAYPOINT(new Vector3(-6.954195f, 0.75f, 6.954196f), 1.00532f));
        waypoints.Add(new WAYPOINT(new Vector3(-8.558396f, 0.75f, 8.558397f), 1.11014f));
        waypoints.Add(new WAYPOINT(new Vector3(-10.33614f, 0.75f, 10.33614f), 1.21626f));
    }`

Comment: Gives NullReference error :/ I call AddWaypoints() in start() func. What could be reason?

Comment: Is `waypoints` initialized? The problem is that your class is not marked `[Serializable]` so the list `waypoints` is not initialized automatically by the inspector. You'll either have to make it `[Serializeable] public class WAYPOINT { ...}` or initialize the list like `public List<WAYPOINT> waypoints = new List<WAYPOINT>();` The first also makes your list and elements visible, editable and stored via the Inspector of the component ;)